# How to suppress android system popups for outgoing sms notifying user's current account balance for a pre-paid network plan?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

My app is able to successfully intercept incoming SMS with a special code. Increased the priority in the manifest intent filter to suppress the broadcast for such special messages using abortBroadcast(). On receiving such special sms the app is supposed to send back an SMS with some info(lets say current location). I have been successfully able to achieve this as well.

The problem is, few of my customers might be on a prepaid plan. This means everytime they send an sms, a system popup comes up telling the remaining balance in their account.

Suppressing the incoming sms broadcast has solved half the problem because my customers dont want to receive these special sms in their inbox nor they want the notification. The problem that remains is how to suppress the outgoing "remaining balance" system popups? Is there a way(for non rooted android) to suppress these notifications?

One way is yes go to setting and manually disable it. That will disable it for all outgoing sms. I dont want my users to do that. I want to programatically suppress only those popups that are a result of sms sent by my app.

I am trying to add this feature for a legitimate use and my customers will be aware of this behavior. I am ok if the customer has to agree to any such settings during the install time(just like device admin policy manager or other usual app permissions).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way(for non rooted android) to suppress these notifications?

AFAIK, there is nothing in Android for this. Most likely, this popup was added by device manufacturers and carriers for their specific plans. You are welcome to talk to each device manufacturer and each carrier to determine if they offer any sort of API for adjusting this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Balance Update / USSD Blocker from Play Store.... so far seems to be working. Available here
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melkote.quietbalance